# Vlookup does not return the result on the index number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am implementing the VLOOKUP in the excel
When I use the index 3 it works
when I put index 4 it does not return anything .

Both the index has some values. It should return . What could be the problem ?

[image]
[image]

This is Monthly sheet columns .. it has columns till M
[image]

Comment: Change the table array to from Monthly!A:C to Monthly!A:M and then use the col_index as 4 that should give you the proper output, you have not considered in your formula the table array for all of the columns included in the monthly sheet.

Comment: Have you considered searcing the StackOverflow or searching in google how to apply a `VLOOKUP()` Funciton, kindly go through the documentation from Microsoft, [VLOOKUP()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Answer (score 1):

You table has 3 columns A, B & C, so using 3 picks the result in column 3, but 4 won't exist as there is no column.

You gave the range in Table_Array as Monthly!A:C, so it won't know about any columns after column C as shown in both your images, only one shown here:

[image]

So do the correction and put Monthly!A:M then you can address the rest of the columns, until then it will not work.

Comment: Nope , it has columns till M . as soon as I make the index 4 , it shows #REF  error.

Comment: You gave the range in Table_Array as Monthly!A:C, so it won't know about any columns after column C.

Comment: Yeah see the new screenshot, the Monthly sheet has column D, E, F .. Why it is not finding them  ?

Comment: @Yogus Seen **ALL** the screenshots and told you what is wrong.